# About the gap of consecutive prime numbers.

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I recently read James Maynard's paper *"Small gaps between primes"*. In his paper, he used the result
$$p_{\pi (k)+k}-p_{\pi (k)+1}\ll k\log k.$$
Here $p_n$ denotes n-th prime number and $\pi (n)$ denotes the number of primes up to $n$. If you know the proof or the reference about this result, please tell me.

Comment: Does it not follow from the Prime Number Theorem?

Comment: Thanks comment. I might be able to prove from the prime number theorem. We use the trivial inequality $k<p_{\pi (k)+1}$ and $p_{\pi (k)+k}\le p_{2k}.$ From these inequality, we have $$p_{\pi (k)+k}-p_{\pi (k)+1} \le p_{2k}-k.$$ The prime number theorem gives $p_{2k}\sim 2k\log (2k).$ Hence we have $$p_{\pi (k)+k}-p_{\pi (k)+1} \sim 2k\log (2k)-k \ll k\log k.$$